# Where is the war against the Edo Tensei people being fought?

Tags: naruto

I'm at around chapter 588 at the moment, and they're currently fighting against the shinobi who have been reincarnated by Kabuto. They seem to be fighting over a wide stretch of land that looks like it could be most places that isn't the desert. I can't remember if they said where they were fighting, but does anyone know approximately where (in relation to the various villages) they are fighting?

Answer (score 1):

If we are to follow the images and information we are given. It should be somewhere in between the [Lands of iron](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Land_of_Iron) and an [island in the Land of Lightning](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Island_Turtle)
This is the current ninja world map.
[image: source]
[source of image](http://static3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110114161253/naruto/images/3/3e/Naruto_World_Map.svg)

Below a piece of the tactic explanation showing a piece of map
[image]

Looking at the 3 borders in the tactics. Taking the angle shape, and the information that it is between the lands of iron and the floating turtle.

[image]

This would be the most logically location for it to be occurring